# Interpolation not going well when trying to plot contour plots / heatmaps on python

Tags: python, scipy, heatmap, contour

I have z values between 0 and 120, but when interpolating I get all kind of values,
like :

> -6644476.02694383, -5957351.6613517 , -5270227.29575958,
> -4583102.93016746, -3895978.56457534, -3208854.19898321,
> -2521729.83339109, -1834605.46779897, -1147481.10220685,
> -460356.73661473,   226767.6289774

And I can see that these are not exceptions when plotting the histograms of values.

Bellow is a subset of x, y and z values, where the problem persists. How can I have a nice heatmap or contour map for this data? and is it as I noticed a problem of interpolation?

Thanks.

```
import os
import scipy.interpolate
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1.9710875 , 1.97108964, 1.97109007, 1.97109292, 1.97109334,
       1.9710962 , 1.95156674, 1.95156508, 1.95157082, 1.95156844,
       1.96684663, 1.96496047, 1.96583682, 1.95277214, 1.94814652,
       1.95401576, 1.93962844, 1.97185149, 1.96532794, 1.96371958,
       1.960543  , 1.9512862 , 1.97803334, 1.96579507, 1.96716609,
       1.96771556, 1.96538601, 1.96611962, 1.96227168, 1.98252509]
y = [41.28326547, 41.28326585, 41.28325479, 41.28325527, 41.28324439,
       41.28324487, 41.26949818, 41.2694979 , 41.26948285, 41.26948246,
       41.28184153, 41.27412078, 41.27296658, 41.26923199, 41.26891926,
       41.270562  , 41.27069284, 41.26754844, 41.2826392 , 41.28118129,
       41.27474794, 41.27390083, 41.2798385 , 41.28465282, 41.28064395,
       41.28030224, 41.2822276 , 41.28023088, 41.28004796, 41.28501738]
z = [ 90.23937225,  90.23937225,  90.33037567,  90.33037567,
        90.33137512,  90.33137512,  84.36405182, 111.60513306,
        82.31817627, 111.61412811,  22.88290024,  42.28657913,
        72.6518631 , 110.51089478,  95.98405457,  63.98109818,
         1.10047495,  58.42002487,  48.07130814,  55.71062851,
        53.7532196 ,  48.63370132,  66.60357666,  46.88467407,
        27.61787987,  39.42815781,  42.52419281,  33.85250854,
        68.59270477,  66.66952515]

f = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z, kind='cubic')

x2 = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 500)
y2 = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), 500)

xx2, yy2 = np.meshgrid(x2, y2)
zz2 = f(x2, y2)

CS = plt.contourf(x2, y2, zz2, 15, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow)

plt.colorbar()  # draw colorbar
# plot data points.
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you try `scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z, kind='linear')`? Does that work?

Comment: Yes I did, same problem.

Comment: The problem is that your grid has many positions outside the convex hull of your data points.  `plt.tricontourf(x, y, z, levels=256, cmap='rainbow'); plt.colorbar()` would only draw inside the hull

Comment: You have very little data points, which vary in value.  Maybe `plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=z, cmap='inferno')` is a better visualization?

Comment: That's a nice way to do it, but I'm more interested in heatmap/contour style visualizations. Just changing the number of levels in `tricontour` has given more interesting results. But ideally I would like some smooth transition on the limits of the plot.

Comment: I have more values, those are just a subset. Now I'm trying to make it more smooth. I'm reading the documentation for `tricontour` it seems promising, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: To get rid of the extreme values, you could try `np.clip(zz2, min(z), max(z), out=zz2)`